# Have a div maintain it's location, change it's size MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is what my system currently looks like on the Overview button:

[image]

When I click one of the buttons, I have it launch a piece of javascript that Renders a partial view inside of a `<div>` like

```
 <div class="container pre-scrollable" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; float:left;height:auto;">
```

However, once the button is clicked, it looks like this:

[image]

Basically, the height stays the same, but the location changes to be beneath the buttons instead of next to it. Is there any way I can have the size increase while staying in the same location?

Comment: use developer tool in your browser by pressing f12. Once there, resize the div in second image to make it sit next to the menu. Then use the css there as the default. You can use !important to make sure that does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply a `max-width:` CSS property to the view's container?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp